# Is there a Python function which sums all values in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to know if there is a Python function to easily sum all the values in a one or two dimensional array?

I have got an array like this:

```
array = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I would normally write Python script like this(or in a function):

```
sum = 0
for i in array:
    sum = sum + i
print(sum)
```

However this become tiresome to write this code in every project I do.
Is there possibly a built-in Python function which would sum all values in an array?

Comment: `sum(array)` will do the job.

Comment: `sum` built-in function already exists

Comment: Pls tell me you googled this and didn't find an answer!

Comment: Please, don't use `sum` as a variable name, its a builtin function already -- in particular, its the exact one you are looking for here.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the function name is `sum`.

```
array = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(sum(array))
```